# Toolbar title not showing in tabbed activity

Tags: java, android

Implemented a tabbed activity using TabsLayout, but now the title of the activity doesn't show on the toolbar, tried various fixes I found on the internet but none seem to work.

activity's xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:title="title"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:tabMode="scrollable">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

OnCreate:
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ordenes_de_viaje_tabbed);

```
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    item = intent.getIntExtra("item", 0);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item);
    Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tabLayout should not be a child of your toolbar it should be below it and user ?attr/actionBarSize witch will give you accurate action bar size regardless to the device dpi

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:title="title"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:tabMode="scrollable">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```